# get binary code from video file c#

Tags: c#, binary

developer
I try this code for get binary

```
public string tobin(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char L in input.ToCharArray())
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(L, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

but when i try to convert binary to video video file couldn't played

```
        string input;
        input = textBox2.Text;
        var bytesAsStrings = input.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 8)
                 .Select(g => new string(g.Select(x => x.Char).ToArray()));
        byte[] bytess = bytesAsStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 2)).ToArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\jefferson\Desktop\q.mp4", bytess);
```

and all of my question is how to get binary code from video file and then convert binary code to video file.
thanks in advance

Comment: But a video *is* binary. However did it end up as a string in the first place? How does a conversion from string to string relate to a binary video file?

Comment: work with `byte[]`.

Comment: my question is how to see binary code of video file

Comment: @elyashiv example please

Comment: Please, re-write your question, it's broad and not very well explained.

Comment: @sergey.quixoticaxis.ivanov hi it's possible to convert video to text file and vice versa it

Comment: @HosseinJafari ofc it's possible, apart the fact that you need binary converters. Otherwise you may use Notepad as a video editor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to see binary code with your eyes. To do so, you need to extract video data while working with byte[] and then you may want to convert byte sequence to any character representation you want (string, char, sequence of '0' and '1', etc.).

Your mistake imho is that you assume that all bytes from your video can be interpreted as valid characters.